# What does it mean ""* and "x"/"X" in helm version?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, semantic-versioning

I've read that [wondeful topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) but there are no answer for some questions:

**1. What is the difference beetween:**

- a) ^0   and ^0.*.0
- b) ^0.0   and ^0.*.0
- c) ^0.0.0   and ^0.*.0
- d) ^0  and ^0.*
  ...

**2. Let say** `~1.2` **means** `1.2.0 <= v < 1.3.0.`

Is there any guarantee that maximun version will be taken or might be taken any version from the range ?

**3. What is the difference between * and x ?**

Answer (score 1):

As you may read about [semantic veersioning (SemVer)](https://semver.org/), the numbers are specified as: `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`.

Now, from [Helm's documentation about the caret `^`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#caret-range-comparisons-major):

> The caret (`^`) comparison operator is for **major** level changes once a stable (**1**.0.0) release has occurred. Prior to a 1.0.0 release the minor versions acts as the API stability level. This is useful when comparisons of API versions as a major change is API breaking. For example,
>
> - `^1.2.3` is equivalent to `>= 1.2.3, < 2.0.0`
> - `^1.2.x` is equivalent to `>= 1.2.0, < 2.0.0`
> - `^2.x` is equivalent to `>= 2.0.0, < 3`
> - `^0.2` is equivalent to `>=0.2.0 <0.3.0`
> - `^0.0` is equivalent to `>=0.0.0 <0.1.0`
> - `^0` is equivalent to `>=0.0.0 <1.0.0`

In short, the caret (`^`) locks your **major** version number, so in all of `^1`, `^1.0.0` the `1` would be locked, and it won't match any version that has a major release number `>1`.

And about the `*` and `x`, from [Helm's documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#wildcards-in-comparisons)

> The `x`, `X`, and `*` characters can be used as **a wildcard character**. This works for all comparison operators. When used on the `=` operator it falls back to the patch level comparison

Which means, `*`, `x` and `X` are all the same. All of them are wildcards and they match any number.

> - `1.2.x` is equivalent to `>= 1.2.0, < 1.3.0`
> - `>= 1.2.x` is equivalent to `>= 1.2.0`
> - `<= 2.x` is equivalent to `< 3`
> - `*` is equivalent to `>= 0.0.0`

And about the tilde (`~`), also refer to the [same page in the documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#tilde-range-comparisons-patch):

> The tilde (`~`) comparison operator is for patch level ranges when a minor version is specified and major level changes when the minor number is missing. For example,
>
> - `~1.2.3` is equivalent to `>= 1.2.3, < 1.3.0`
> - `~2.3` is equivalent to `>= 2.3, < 2.4`
> - `~1.2.x` is equivalent to `>= 1.2.0, < 1.3.0`

See more:

- https://semver.org/
- https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#working-with-prerelease-versions
- https://semver.npmjs.com/

Comment: you didn't answer for some questions:

Let's say we have 1.0.0 1.0.1 1.0.2 1.0.3 1.1.0 in the repo 

And I use ^1.

Is it guaranteed that 1.1.0 will be taken ? Most people rely in it but I don't see any phrase in documentation about it

Comment: From their source code, it appears that they [fetch first element from the sorted repo tags list](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/internal/resolver/resolver.go#L177), and the sort is [ascending](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/e007c900ce5f2233c8583565d5ba1b0433b1a213/pkg/registry/client.go#L594), see [go/semver](https://github.com/Masterminds/semver#working-with-prerelease-versions) package, and [this snippets](https://go.dev/play/p/BZNoALlaiDf) replicates that logic. So yes,  1.1.0  will be taken

Comment: I prefer to rely on documentation (contract) because implementation could be changed.